# Remove a directory in R invoking linux commands

Tags: r, unlink

I am writing code using R that invokes Linux commands to create a directory with multiple files which has to be deleted at the end.

I tried using `file.remove(directory_name)` which removed the directory only when its empty. If the directory has files, `file.remove` didn’t work. `unlink(directory_name)` didn't remove the directory.

**My code:**

```
dir.create("./dir1")  
dir.create("./dir2")  
............  
............  
............  
file.remove("./dir1")  
unlink("./dir1, recursive = TRUE")
```

`file.remove()` threw an error:

> cannot remove file './dir1', reason 'Directory not empty'.

while, `unlink()` didn't remove the directory.

How do I delete a directory with files in it?

Comment: If you first use `unlink` to remove the files from the directory, you can then delete the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To `unlink` recursively, you need to pass the `recursive = TRUE` as an additional parameter:

**This:**

```
 unlink("./dir1", recursive = TRUE)
```

**Not this:**

```
unlink("./dir1, recursive = TRUE")
```

Comment: You are welcome.  The best way to say thank you on Stack overflow is via upvotes for any answer you find useful.